# Ambiguous reference to member '=='

Tags: ios, swift, operators, arithmetic-expressions

That must be a basic mistake, but I can't see what is wrong in this code:

```
.... object is some NSManagedObject ....
let eltType = ((object.valueForKey("type")! as! Int) == 0) ? .Zero : .NotZero
```

At compile time, I get this message:

```
Ambiguous reference to member '=='
```

Comparing an Int to 0 doesn't seem ambiguous to me, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem is that the compiler has
no information what type the values `.Zero`, `.NotZero` refer to.

The problem is also unrelated to managed objects or the `valueForKey`
method, you would get the same error message for

```
func foo(value: Int) {
    let eltType = value == 0 ? .Zero : .NotZero // Ambiguous reference to member '=='
    // ...
}
```

The problem can be solved by specifying a fully typed value

```
let eltType = value == 0 ? MyEnum.Zero : .NotZero
```

or by providing a context from which the compiler can infer the type:

```
let eltType: MyEnum = value == 0 ? .Zero : .NotZero
```

Comment: It is true that by adding the type it works. But if instead of using the ternary operator I use the form if () {...} else {...} then it works without the type. I don't quite see the difference. The information at the disposal of the compiler for type inferring seems to be the same.

Comment: @Michel: What exactly is the if/else statement that works without the type?

Comment: Looking again at what I did, I may have given the type at some point, when declaring the variable. Making what you wrote right.

Comment: I had same error message, and specifying the full type enum case fixed the issue. But my case was could be inferred automatically, the left side of the assignment was a property of the class so the type was declared. `state = (cats.count == 0) ?
                .noData(parentNode: pNode) : .content(parentNode: pNode, childCategories: cats)`. @MartinR do you have any idea what this is still unclear for the compiler to infer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bracelet seems to works :

`let eltType = (object.valueForKey("type")! as! Int) == 0 ? .Zero : .NotZero`

Comment: Removing the parentheses doesn't make any difference for me.